# Connecting ESP8266 to website

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I would like to control a relay using Wemos D! R1 via a website from anywhere. I managed to control it using local web server and now would like to step it up further.

I'm using the following code which connects to this [website](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1) and retrieve data as JSON perfectly.

```js
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "PASS";
 
void setup () {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(1000);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
}
 
void loop() {
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { //Check WiFi connection status
        Serial.println("");                     
        HTTPClient http;  //Declare an object of class HTTPClient
        http.begin("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1");  //Specify request destination
        int httpCode = http.GET();                                                                  //Send the request
    
        if (httpCode > 0) { //Check the returning code
            String payload = http.getString();   //Get the request response payload
            Serial.println("");                  // Empty Line
            Serial.println(payload);             //Print the response payload
            //////////////// Json code
              StaticJsonDocument<2000> doc;
              DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);
              if (error) {
                Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
                Serial.println(error.c_str());
                return;
              }
              const char* sensor = doc["name"];
              const char* username = doc["username"];
              const char* email = doc["email"];
              const char* address = doc["address"];
              Serial.println(sensor);
              Serial.println(username);
              Serial.println(email);
              Serial.println(address);
            //////////////// End of Json Code
              http.end();   //Close connection
              while ( 0 < 1 ){ delay(10000); }  // to break the loop
            }
    }
    delay(10);    //Send a request every 30 seconds
}
```

I made a web page that makes AJAX call to a PHP file to retrieve data from MYSQL DB, but when I run it, the monitor keeps printing empty lines forever although connected successfully to my WIFI.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json', // added data type
    data: ({mobile: 'hi'}),
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
});
```

The result I'm getting from AJAX is (which you can check visiting this [link](https://payond.net/ard/):

```
    {"status":"ON"}
```

I'm using the following code on php file:

```js
<?php 
header('Content-type: application/json');   
require 'functions.php'; 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $catrecord = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `ard`");
        while($catinfo = mysqli_fetch_array($catrecord, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ $Cat = $catinfo['status']; }
    $responseArray = array('status' => $Cat );          

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);     
    header('Content-Type: application/json');   
    echo $encoded;
} else {    
    echo $responseArray['status'];      
}
?>
```

Comment: check the returning code. 200 is OK. all others are an error. negative return values are a local error. positive are a HTTP error

Comment: What is the exact question? You don't know how to modified the Arduino code to receive json payload of `{"status":"on"}`?

Comment: you can use port forwarding or websockets to control from the WAN. or hammer the php site from the wemos, but that's not as good as talking to the esp server directly or having always-on streaming.

Comment: @dandavis "talking to the esp server directly or having always-on streaming." would you please elaborate more or share a link about this methodology. Thx

Comment: You should do what @Juraj suggested. The way it's written now, your code won't correctly report errors which would hide the cause of the problem you're seeing.